# How to save two collections using save button - backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have two views each bound with their own collections. i have a save button on the screen on third view.

How can i save both the collections in single save click?

Comment: could you provide some code? otherwise the answer is: call the save methods of both collections from your click event handler method. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code to help us answering you, but I'll try to help. Here is some code that you could implement:

```
var View3 = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click .saveButton' : 'saveCollections'
  },

  initialize: function(view1, view2) {
   this.view1 = options.view1;
   this.view2 = options.view2; 
  },

  saveCollections: function() {
    this.view1.collection.save();
    this.view2.collection.save();
  }
});
```

You'll need to pass as params your previous views (**View1** and **View2**) in the instantiation of your **View3**.

Comment: Awesome... It worked.. Actually i did not know if i should be passing views like that.

One more question? Is it good practice to pass views like that? or is there any other way?

Also, i did not provide the code as i did not write any. I was just designing my views and models and came across to this issue so thought would clarify before i write any code.

Thanks again

Comment: It is a very good practice to pass views like that. It's one of the best solutions to reference other objects/functions/modules/etc inside  other objects/functions/modules.

Comment: You should also check http://marionettejs.com if you are planning to work with a medium/large application.